# Is it possible to get latest version of medit (aka mooedit) for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, package-management, software-installation, text-editor

Sometimes I use [medit](http://mooedit.sourceforge.net/download.html). It is available only for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/medit) at old 1.2.0-3 version.

Is it possible to get latest Medit for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual compilation of latest medit (aka mooedit) 1.2.92 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal) is possible by using below commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libiculx60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libiculx60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev build-essential debhelper dh-autoreconf dh-python dh-strip-nondeterminism dpkg-dev g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 \
gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools intltool libasan4 libatk1.0-dev libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev \
libcilkrts5 libexpat1-dev libffi-dev libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgcc-7-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev \
libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev \
libicu-le-hb0 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libpango1.0-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpixman-1-dev libpng-dev \
libpthread-stubs0-dev libpython2-dev libpython2.7-dev libquadmath0 libsm-dev libstdc++-7-dev libtool libtsan0 libubsan0 libx11-dev libxau-dev \
libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev \
libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev linux-libc-dev m4 make pkg-config po-debconf python-cairo \
python-dev python-gobject-2 python-gobject-2-dev python-gtk2-dev python2.7-dev python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 \
x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-randr-dev \
x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev

wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/mooedit/files/medit/1.2.92/medit-1.2.92-devel.tar.bz2/download -O medit-1.2.92-devel.tar.bz2
tar -xf medit-1.2.92-devel.tar.bz2
cd medit-1.2.92-devel
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

and enjoy:

[image: mooedit 1.2.92 on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS]